# Variable declaration inside bash script while loop

Tags: bash, variables, while-loop

As expected this prints every line of the 'testEmpty' file to the console.

```
while read i; do
    echo $i
done < testEmpty
```

....but this:

```
while read i; do
    name=$i
    echo $name
done < testEmpty
```

only prints out blanks lines.

The reason I am doing this is because on each line of the 'testEmpty' file there is a URL which I am feeding to curl within this same while loop (removed for clarity) and I wish to append a file extension to part of the url to serve as a filename and I thought it would be quite neat to do this in the same loop.

BTW The 'testEmpty' file should only ever really have only 1 or maybe 2 entries so I'm not bothered about overhead etc. which I believe could well be an issue if I were processing huge files, so I have no need to worry about that.

Thank you

Comment: please input your sample file and desire output

Comment: Did you try "while read i; do name=$i; echo $i; done < testEmpty"?

Comment: For the code I've given above I expect the 2 loops to do the same thing - print each line of the 'testEmpty' file to the console. Once I've figured out why they don't and how I can make them do that I will  alter 'i' and feed the result to 'name' to be used by curl as the file name

Comment: I executed my line above and it worked. I am missing the semicolons in you code...

Comment: @lanes Yes, and it DOES output each line of the file.........

Comment: @lanes so how now do I alter $i (say run it through sed for example) and save the result to $name ?

Comment: @user1587462, actually, using `sed` isn't typically the right way to do an alteration; bash has native string-manipulation functionality built in. For instance, `name=${i//$foo/$bar}` will save the expanded contents of `$i` to `$name`, replacing `$foo` with `$bar`.

Comment: @user1587462 ...see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100 for general information on string manipulation in bash, or http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073 for a shorter description focused on parameter expansion.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks. Using the native string manipulation of bash instead of sed worked a treat. The website you suggested was excellent also.

Comment: The second code block in your question works just as well as the first. Presumably you haven't posted the real code where the problem appeared.

Answer (score 3):

@CharlesDuffy had it when he suggested that using sed was not the right way to do string manipulation. The simple answer to the question is this:

```
while read i; do
    name=${i}
    echo $name
done < testEmpty
```

Answer (score 0):

This form

```
name=$i echo $name
```

will substitute the variables *before* launching the command, so when `echo` actually runs, bash sees

```
name="contents of the line" echo
```

Also, you won't get the value of the *previous* line because `var=value cmd ...` only sets the `var` variable in the environment of the command *for the duration of the command*.

You'll need to ensure the variable is set before you want it dereferenced:

```
name=$i; echo $name
# or if you're launching some other command, protect the variable:
name=$i sh -c 'echo $name'
```

Comment: The assignment was on a separate line; the lack of indentation in the original post hid that.

Comment: @chepner it was, I hadn't realised when I posted. Apologies for that.

Comment: Oh. Well in that case, apart from the lack of quotes, I don't understand why it "didn't work".